# 500: Internal Server Error in using PHPMailer

Tags: php, error-handling, phpmailer, internal-server-error

I'm trying to send an email using the following code and I'm getting Internal Server Error. I am not sure why I am having this trouble.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';  
    $mail->Password = "mypasswordhere";           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress('myemail@gmail.com');
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
?>
```

I just placed this file as test.php inside the PhpMail folder after extracting it. Like the below

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a single quote on the line:

```
$mail->Password = 'mypasswordhere';
```

The error behind is probably a PHP parsing error, which is shown in your Apache error log.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the problem. It's a typo error while I pasted my code here and replaced my actual password with that.

Comment: yes especially when you have turened of error reporting.

Comment: Try `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to show errors.

Comment: Yep, I turned off error reporting.

Comment: Yep, sorry. that would help. Thanks.

Comment: @Kerry please be a good supporter and accept helpful answers

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - You also missed a single quote at the end. Haven't you?